# how to make a dropdownlist visible once clicking a button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu, onclick

I am a beginner,
Hope one can help me with my problem,
I want to make a drop down list visible once I click the button,
It completely like the thing that has been done here:
[https://shop.adidas.co.in/#category/Pag-60/No-0/0/All/*facet*.DIVISION_CATEGORY_ss:%28%22FOOTWEAR%22%29%20AND%20allBrands_ss:%28%22ORIGINALS%22%29](https://shop.adidas.co.in/#category/Pag-60/No-0/0/All/_facet_.DIVISION_CATEGORY_ss:%28%22FOOTWEAR%22%29%20AND%20allBrands_ss:%28%22ORIGINALS%22%29)

when the customer clicks on Buy button then a drop-down list appear above of the buy button,I think this example in the mentioned website is clear enough,

**EDITION**

as the code shows, when I click on BUY button it opens up a new link,
I'm not wanna to do this, 
at first when someone click the button it has to not work and just show the drop-down list,
secondly, when the user chooses a size from the drop-down list and then click on the button it has to work and open the link,

it is exactly what happen in the above link that I have introduced.
my stuff:

```
<button name="buySize" id="buySize" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { Barcode = @item.Barcode },"")'">
    خرید &raquo;
</button>
<div class="pull-left">
    <label class="control-label" id="drpSize">سایز:</label>
    <div class="product-quantity" id="drpSize" >
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CartItems[0].Size, new SelectList(Model.Sizes))
    </div>
</div>
```

this was my drop-down list and button
and also javascript :`

```
$('#buySize').click(function () {
    if (this.click())
        $('#drpSize').show("fast");
    else
        $('#drpSize').hide("fast");
});
```

every help is appreciating :),

Comment: are there any error messages? I think `this` should be `$(this)`

Comment: This jquery code is totally incorrect

Comment: @TomDoodler No error is rised but not work simply

Comment: @MayankPandey maybe is incorrect as I told I am beginner, May I ask you to get that correct

Comment: You can not really correct it because nobody understands what it is supposed to do

Comment: @TomDoodler did you visit the link I published? in that if you go above one shoes then click BUY button, a dropdown list will be appeared, the thing that I am looking for is done in that link,why you think no one can help me so ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put drop down list hidden by default using `style` attribute in drop down `div` as

```
style="display:none"
```

on click of button you can show the drop down list.
For this code will be as follow:

CSHTML

> EDIT: You achieve required functionality First remove onclick event
>   from button control.

```
 <button name="buySize" id="buySize" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
  خرید &raquo;</button>
   <div class="pull-left">
     <label class="control-label" id="drpSize">سایز:</label>
      <div class="product-quantity" id="drpSize" style="display:none" >
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CartItems[0].Size, new SelectList(Model.Sizes))                                                              </div>
    </div>
```

in js file

```
 $('#buySize').click(function () {
           $('#drpSize').css('display','block'); 
        });
```

> EDIT: alternately if want to show drop down with animated effect and
>   want to open BUY link after size selection use this script.

```
 $('#buySize').click(function () {
   $('#drpSize').show('fast');
var val= $('#dropDownId :selected').text();
if(val!='Select'){
location.href= //which ever link you want to open put here
}
 });
```

Comment: don't forget to include `jquery.js` file

Comment: thank you so much my friend, in fact it worked and when I clicked the buy Button dropDown appeared, But Buy Button opened the link instead of not working to allow user to select a size, I update the post please read that , thank again :)

Comment: as the code shows, when I click on BUY button it opens up a new link, I'm not wanna to do this, at first when someone click the button it has to not work and just show the drop-down list, secondly, when the user chooses a size from the drop-down list and then click on the button it has to work and open the link,

Comment: thank you my friend , but I donno how to provide the link with a parameter in  the JS, I mean , as you can see in the link for the Buy, there is barcode parameter that must be sent, how I can sen that to the JS, sorry if the question is continueing ,

Comment: It also shows just the label of the size not the dropdown list

Comment: have you replaced `dropDownId`  in this code `$('#dropDownId :selected').text();` with actual 'id' of dropdown

Comment: Another thing is that when I click one buy button , then all other buy button that there is on the page not work anymore . (detailed infromation: this is a page with 50 products, each product has this button , exact the same as the link I provided in the post ) ; thx again for your time

Comment: As I did not know how to provide the parameter, I just test the first option

Comment: I tested your second option too (with a constant barcode for the link that I had problem) It was as the same as the first option in functioning, I hope you can help me, again thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Your dropdown is initially hide by the css ie. display:none

Jquery code to show it when user click on buy button:

```
$('#buySize').click(function () {
   $('#dropdown_id').show();
});
```

Comment: thank you for your code, but it did not work, I should say that, BUY button is supposed to open another page. so firstly we should stop it from opening the buy page, in a way at first it show the drop down list then user again can click the button to buy what they like. I hope this explanation be clear. I also update the post. thanks again